# Store results of django databse textfield in a string list

Tags: python, django

I have a django model that contains a textfield with a large amount of text. I would like to be able to query the database for this textfield and store the results in a string list. How can I do this?

something like...

views.py:

```
queryset = Words.object.filter(id='1') 
wordArray = []
wordArray = queryset.split() # obviously this doesn't work
```

models.py

```
class Words (models.Model):
    dictionary = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.dictionary)
```

Comment: I need it as a split list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
result = Words.object.filter(id='1').values_list('dictionary',flat=True)
```

then to access each value and split it proceed as follows:

```
r_list=[]
for r in result:
    r_list.append(r.split())
```

`r_list` will have all the word of all values in result.

Comment: This is does get the value as a list, but is storing each character as a new entry. I need to split it based on spaces.

Comment: can you post/comment the output you are getting?

Comment: well in my view im doing
```{% for x in object%}
<li>{{X}}</li>
{%endfor%}```

but in the browser it appears as
*e
*x
*a
*m
*p
*l
*e

Comment: and what is the value of object? is it `'example'` or `['example']` you should get the later one. And it would be more help ful if you can post your models

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand what you are asking. Object seems to be just one long string still

Comment: `values_list` returns a list and not just one value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150464/discussion-between-sasuke-and-mason).